# Android problem with PHP org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json, database, authentication

I'm trying to make the LogIn of my app but I have this error

org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

My android/Java code is fine because the same code in works to de SingIn and I think the error is in the php file

```
<?php
```

require "conexion.php";

```
$rol=$_POST["rol"];
$contraseña=$_POST["contraseña"];

$contra_hash= password_hash($contraseña, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = "SELECT rol,contraseña FROM datos_perfil WHERE rol='$rol' AND contraseña='$contra_hash' ";
$response = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();
$result['login']= array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($response) > 0){

    $row = mysqlo_fetch_assoc($response);

    if (password_verify($contra_hash,$row['contraseña']) ){

        $index['rol']= $row['rol'];
        $index['nombre']= $row['nombre'];

        array_push($result['login'],$index);

        $result['success']="1";
        $result["message"]= "success";

        echo json_encode($result);
        echo "AHHH";
        mysqli_close($con);

    }else{
        $result["success"]="0";
        $result["message"]= "error";
        echo json_encode($result);

    }
}
```

"contraseña" is password and "rol" is some kind of ID

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: What is the PHP error?